# Is the character \n in C/C++ and Java considered to be LF or platform dependent?

Tags: java, c++, c, newline

This question is with regards to '\n' in C, C++ and Java. For each of the respective languages, is the '\n' character platform dependent(LF on unix CRLF on windows) or it is only LF regardless of the platform

Comment: It is the _line separator_ that is platform dependent, not the new-line character.

Comment: Bad idea to mix [C],[C++] and [Java] in a single question...

Comment: @MatteoItalia - unless the answer is the same for all of them. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker: as far as I can see from the Java documentation, it's not. :)

Comment: '\n' in C is only 1 char. It's not necessarily the value 10 (ASCII LF).

Comment: @MatteoItalia - whoops, I forgot: Java does the "if it might be a line terminator, then it is one" dance. But '\n' in Java **is** a new line, on all platforms...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C and C++ `\n` is **the** newline character to be used in strings inside the application. The conversion to the platform-specific newline sequence is done by the IO streams when opened in text mode (i.e. not in binary mode).

Notice that this is true for the standard library, but may not hold for particular APIs - e.g. I remember that some Windows controls needed an explicit CRLF to work correctly.

As for Java, I may be wrong (I almost never worked in Java), but from what I can see from the documentation the streams don't perform any translation; instead, you can use [`System.lineSeparator()`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29) to obtain the current platform's line separator. Using this information, `BufferedWriter` provides a handy `newLine` method to output a newline to the underlying stream.

Comment: What if I want to output CRLF or CR or LF only independent of the platform, can I simply use \x<HexCode>\x<HexCode>, etc?

Comment: @shawn open the file in binary mode (to avoid automatic translation) and use `\r` for CR, `\n` for LF. Also the hex codes are ok, but they are longer to type. :-)